# Conversion Overflow Error in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I am getting error that i am not able to fix

i have field where only numbers are allowed and  maximum of 10 digits can be entered

here is code for checking digits

```
char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8 && ch != 46)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

but when try to execute the  i am getting this error popup message

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6Zy03YC.png?1]

Comment: I removed the sql tag.

Comment: The max value for an integer is 2147483647 so, when you pass the value "9999999999" to your database engine you receive correctly the error message. You should limit your value to the maximum allowed for an integer. However I am curious to see the code that tries to write that value to your datatable.

Comment: thanks everyone changed my type to big int now no problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has probably nothing to do with WPF.

As you are probably using MS SQL, you may want to take a look at [ranges of integer types in MS SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

It says that maximal possible value for integer(int, int32) column is 2,147,483,647, while your value is 9999999999, that is far greater than 2 billions.

You should change the datatype for the column to `bigint`.

**EDIT:**

Also, if your data entities(queries) are created manually, then you should use in C# program [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64(v=vs.110).aspx)(long) type corresponding to the SQL `bigint` type.

**ALSO ABOUT WPF**

While it is possible to handle the data validation in the code-behind event handling, the intricacies of WPF and overall drawbacks of such approach can lead to many problems, so I'd recommended you to move your validation code to the viewmodel classes and use some of the standard [WPF Validation techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation).

Answer (score 2):

9,999,999,999 is more then `int32` max value (that is 2,147,483,647. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx))

use `int64` instead (int64 max value is: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx))